# ffmpeg: How to include dynamic path in m3u8 playlist? (Playlist and segments are in different directories.)

Tags: ffmpeg, prefix, subdirectory, playlist, segment

I have a live webcam stream, I use ffmpeg to cut it to 10-second segments, stream it live, and store the segments in a day/hour directory structure.

```
ffmpeg.exe [input]
-f segment
-strftime 1
-segment_format mpegts
-segment_time 10
-segment_list_size 6
-segment_list "D:\cams\cam1\live.m3u8"
-segment_list_type m3u8
"D:\cams\cam1\%a\%H\%M%S.ts"
```

So my "live.m3u8" and my segments are in different directories (the segments are in a subdirectory). By default when ffmpeg generates the m3u8 list it only adds the filename: instead of `Fri/12/1234.ts` the filename line is only `1234.ts`, so it's obviously not working.

There is an option `segment_list_entry_prefix` to add the path as a prefix, but my prefix is dynamic (`%a/%H/`). For some reason, the dynamic arguments are not working: instead of `Fri/12/1234.ts` the playlist has `%a/%H/1234.ts`.

Is it an ffmpeg bug, or something's missing from my command? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routine that writes out the list entry extracts the basename of each segment, so it can't be done at present. Try the [HLS](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2) muxer.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that will be the solution after all. I started this project with the HLS muxer, then for some reason I don't remember I went with the classic segment muxer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is what you need?

```
-hls_segment_filename "video/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%s.ts"
```